# Creating a new random number in a static method

Tags: java, gridworld

I am trying to make a simple game in gridworld where your ship passes through and asteriod belt. The asteroid belt is supposed to have one empty space in it every time it is generated. I have a method called nextAsteroidField() that creates this belt my implementaion for it is this

```
public static void nextAsteroidField()
{
    int randNum = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
    for(int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if(i == randNum)
        {
        }
        else
            world.add(new Location(0, i), new Asteroid());
    }
}
```

the method has to be static because it is being called from the main of the class when the first asteroid belt is created.

The first time this method is called it creates the space like intended. I call this method every time the previous row of asteroids runs into the bottom of the grid. The second time and every other time after has no gap.

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: The first time this method is called it creates the space like intended. I call this method every time the previous row of asteroids runs into the bottom of the grid. The second time and every other time after has no gap. Sorry

Comment: Your current randNum is between 1 and 15 and you iterate 1 through 15, the problem to me doesn't seem to be in here, what is world and how do you add asteroids at a given location? I see no problem with the random part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Random class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main{

static Random rnd = new Random();

public static void main( String[] args ){
    int randNum = rnd.nextInt( 16 )+1;
    for( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
        if( i != randNum )
            System.out.print("*");
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: @home Ah, of course. Thanks for the feedback! (I'm new). Though, I honestly don't know why the original code is not working. It works for me, if I create the asteroids as stars.

Answer (score 0):

If it works the first time you call `nextAsteroidField()` but not the second (or third...), then I think your problem is, that you don't remove the asteroids from your world.

Change your method to look like this:

```
public static void nextAsteroidField()
{
    world.clearAsteroids(); //Clear the world, so no other asteroids block the gap
                            //Of course, you have to write this function ;)
    int randNum = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
    for(int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if(i != randNum)
            world.add(new Location(0, i), new Asteroid());
    }
}
```